# how to forward all UDP traffic to VPN client IP with ufw

Tags: firewall, udp, ufw

I'm using sipgate with freepbx and I've got down to what I presume is the final hurdle with the one-way audio issue.

From everything I've read the issue points to NAT. I need to forward **all UDP traffic** to the IP 192.168.0.2 (this is the VPN client IP on ppp0 which is the freepbx box). I am using ufw as the firewall on the VPN server.

/etc/ufw/before.rules:

```
*nat

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow forward traffic to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5060 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 5060 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2


# Process the NAT table rules
COMMIT
```

So far I'm receiving calls perfectly, caller can hear but I'm not getting any audio back.

How do I forward **all UDP traffic** coming into the VPN server to the ip 192.168.0.2?

**UPDATE:**

/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf uncommented:

```
net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding=1
net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1
```

**Added:**

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1:54000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
```

No errors but I think the above rule might be correct as there's no errors on firewall start up. Audio issue still ongoing but this is not relative to unix SE.